# Access User before determining the Route in UseRouting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.1

I am currently building a middle-ware in which I would like to rewrite the route and I need access to the authenticated user. For the first requirement I need to place my middle-ware before the `UseRouting()`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.MyMiddleware(); // I need to access the User e.g. the ClaimsPrinciple right here.

    app.UseRouting(); // This fixes the route

    app.UseAuthentication(); // This determines the User e.g. the ClaimsPrinciple
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

As you can see, that is a somewhat Circle of Tuffs. Due to how the framework is build, I need to place `UseAuthentication()` after `UseRouting()`. On the other hand I want my middle-ware to access the user before `UseRouting()` which would mean I have to place `UseAuthentication()` before `UseRouting()`.

Therefore, is there any way to access the `ClaimsPrinciple` before `UseRouting()`?